# iOS: how to create views programatically using XIB, but without using View Controller

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am trying to fill a scroll view with a number of subviews that are identical, except the data changes. If I want to do the whole thing programatically, I can, like so:

```
int width = 110;
int count = 0;
self.scrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(width*[items count],100);

for (NSString *id in items) {
    Item *item = [items objectForKey:id];
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(count*width, 0, 100, 100);
    UIView *itemSubview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];

    CGRect dataLabelFrame = CGRectMake( 0, 52, 35, 30 );
    UILabel* dataLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: dataLabelFrame];
    dataLabel.text = @"Data specific to item"; // item.property or something
    dataLabel.font:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:30];
    dataLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.0];

    [itemSubview addSubview:dataLabel];
    [self.scrollView addSubview:itemSubview];
    [itemSubview release];
}
```

All good. Now, how do I do the same thing if my subView is a little more complex, and I want to lay it out with Interface Builder and a xib archive? So far I have:

- created my own custom view code, ItemSubview, extending UIView with an IBOutlet NSString *dataLabel
- created my xib file, set the file's owner to be of class ItemSubview, and hooked up my label to the outlet

then, in code:

```
int width = 110;
int count = 0;
self.scrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(width*[items count],100);

for (NSString *id in items) {
    Item *item = [items objectForKey:id];
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(count*width, 0, 100, 100);
    ItemSubview *itemSubview = [[ItemSubview alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    [itemSubview setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.2 blue:0.0 alpha:0.2]]; // to see where it ends up

    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ItemSubview" owner:itemSubview options:nil];
    itemSubview.dataLabel.text = @"Data specific to item"; // item.property or something
    [self.scrollView addSubview:itemSubview];
    [itemSubview release];
}
```

When I do this, my itemSubview gets drawn (I can see the background color of the itemSubview), but not the dataLabel that was in the xib archive. What am I missing/not understanding? Why does this work programatically, but not with a xib file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
    NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ItemSubview" owner:self options:nil];
    ItemSubview *itemSubview = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];
```

Make sure that in your xib file, the top level view is of class ItemSubview, and that dataLabel is properly hooked up to ItemSubview's outlet. File's owner should be left blank.

Comment: That helped. The itemSubview came out of the xib with background and size, but it still did not display it's dataLabel sub-sub-view. (Not even the default value set in the xib.) The file's owner is blank, and the outlet from the dataLabel is hooked up to the itemSubview (which is the sole top-level object in the xib). The debugger says the label is there, with the correct value, but it's not getting on screen. Hmmm...

Comment: That is odd. I notice that you wrote that ItemSubview class has an IBOutlet that is an NSString*. Shouldn't that be a UILabel*? I think that is probably just a typo in the question though. You could try this: delete the xib file completely, restart Xcode and recreate the xib file. Sometime Xcode just gets messed up. Other than that, maybe post the exact code that you are using to add the subViews, the ItemSubview class, and an image of your xib file set up.

Comment: My problem, it turns out, was the [itemSubview release]. So, with that removed, all is good.